# Retornar total de cada pedido com MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Imaginem que eu tenha uma tabela `pedidos` com os seguintes campos:

[image]

E que eu tenha outras duas tabelas (`pedido_a`, `pedido_b`) de dois tipos distintos de pedidos como os exemplos abaixo:

[image]
[image]

Cada item da tabela `pedidos` pode ter *"n"* itens da tabela `pedido_a` **OU** da `pedido_b`. Um pedido pode ser de apenas um tipo ("A" ou "B", nunca uma mistura dos dois).

O que eu estou tentando fazer, é montar uma query que retorne uma lista com todos os pedidos (`pedidos`) junto com o valor total de cada um, de acordo com o seu respectivo tipo.

A lógica já está definida, mas eu estou com problemas ao tentar passá-la para SQL. Segue uma imagem ilustrando o processo que eu imaginei:

[image]

Como eu conseguiria passar esta lógica para uma consulta SQL?

Comment: se você criar um campo total do pedido na tabela principal pedidos, e no momento da criação do pedido, calcular o total e gravar ali, acho facilitaria muito a sua vida...

Comment: @Jader já pensei nessa alternativa e realmente é uma boa solução. Mas o problema é que atualmente isto não é uma possibilidade (alterar a estrutura da tabela e/ou do código). Só é possível a realização de consultas mesmo.

Comment: O `valor` nas tabelas já é o valor total do pedido ou é necessário multiplicar pelas quantidades?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly A coluna `valor` se refere ao valor unitário, portanto é sim necessário multiplicar pelas quantidades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz a consulta supondo que seja necessário multiplicar a quantidade pelo valor, mais caso não seja é só remover a multiplicação.

```
select p.id
 , p.tipoPedido
 , IF( p.tipoPedido = 'A'
     , SUM(pa.quantidade * pa.valor)
     , SUM((pb.quantidadeTamanho1 + pb.quantidadeTamanho2 + pb.quantidadeTamanho3) * pb.valor))
  from pedido p
  left join pedido_a pa on p.id=pa.idPedido
  left join pedido_b pb on p.id=pb.idPedido
 group by p.id
```

segue exemplo no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba5dad/4)

Comment: Sim, a quantidade precisava ser multiplicada pelo valor, e a query funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!